# makefile error: undefined reference to main

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to compile my piece of code using make. Normally I compile my code like this:

```
mipsisa32r2el-timesys-linux-gnu-g++ -o testing -I/usr/include/libxml2 -L/develop/xc4/rootfs/parsecpp/lib -L/develop/xc4/rootfs/parsecpp/sqlite-mips2/lib -I/develop/xc4/rootfs/parsecpp/sqlite-mips2/include db.cpp main.cpp networkinterfacemodule.cpp network.cpp multiplex.cpp program.cpp service.cpp -lsqlite3 -lxml2
```

To get rid of this long command I tried to write a makefile:

```
CC= mipsisa32r2el-timesys-linux-gnu-g++

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/parsecpp/sqlite-mips2/lib:/parsecpp/lib:/tmp/vixs_temp/DirectFB/single_core/lib


CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/develop/xc4/rootfs/parsecpp/sqlite-mips2/include

LDFLAGS=-L/develop/xc4/rootfs/parsecpp/lib -L/develop/xc4/rootfs/parsecpp/sqlite-mips2/lib

LIBS = -lsqlite3 -lxml2

PROG=testing

all: main.o db.o mod.o multiplex.o network.o networkinterfacemodule.o program.o service.o
    $(CC) -o $(PROG) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)  main.o db.o mod.o multiplex.o network.o networkinterfacemodule.o program.o service.o $(LIBS) 

main.o: main.cpp 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) main.cpp db.cpp networkinterfacemodule.cpp mod.cpp multiplex.cpp network.cpp program.cpp service.cpp $(LIBS)

db.o: db.cpp 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) db.cpp $(LIBS)


mod.o: mod.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) mod.cpp $(LIBS)

multiplex.o: multiplex.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) multiplex.cpp $(LIBS)

network.o: network.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) network.cpp $(LIBS)

networkmoduleinterface.o: networkinterfacemodule.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) networkinterfacemodule.cpp $(LIBS)

program.o: program.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) program.cpp $(LIBS)

service.o: service.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) service.cpp $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -rf *o testing
```

Then I get this error:

```
/opt/timesys/linux-gnu/toolchain/bin/../../toolchain/lib/crt1.o: In function `__start':
(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `main'
/opt/timesys/linux-gnu/toolchain/bin/../../toolchain/lib/crt1.o: In function `__start':
(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [db.o] Error 1
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I like how the makefile is several times longer than the entire command.

Comment: `rm -rf *o testing`: Do you really want to delete all files and directories ending in the character "o"?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, but it should save compilation times, no biggie. However it could be written much more compactly, sure.

Comment: @sth Actually it does not matter

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the entire console output after running Make?

Comment: `%.o:%.cpp,%.h\n\t$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o %<` (where `\n` is a new line and `\t` is a tab character) is a generic rule to *compile* (IIRC, check the manual) that can replace all your manually deployed rules for compiling each translation unit.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Whenever you are just compiling a file and not linking it, use the "-c" flag.

For example :-

```
db.o: db.cpp 
$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) db.cpp $(LIBS)
```

Also, while compiling, there's *no need* to provide "$(LIBS)" to the compiler, only provide them when linking. Nor do you need the linker flags since linker is not called when using the "-c" flag.

So you could write,

```
 db.o: db.cpp 
 $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) db.cpp
```

---

UPDATED (based on comments):-

When linking the files, the linker expects one and only one `main` function. In the above case, the main function is not defined in `db.cpp` and hence although compilation succeeds, the linker throws an error as it cannot find the `main` function.

Comment: That is okay. But the question is : why linking would fail if OP does that?

Comment: +1 Addtitionally, you can avoid much of the cost of writing the makefile by writing rules (or letting the default rules work.

Comment: @Nawaz: If you try to *link* every translation unit by itself the linker will fail to find the `main` function, that is present only in one of the translation units.

Comment: C/C++ programs require a starting point, which is the `main` function. When a program is compiled *and* linked, the compiler requires this "main" function to be defined. In your case, an individual file is being compiled and linked, but it doesn't contain the "main" function (that is what I assume from the error), hence the error.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, I guess Nawaz knows it, he just wants this to be a part of the answer.

Comment: @rajatkhanduja, you should add this to the answer itself instead of the comments.

Comment: @rajatkhanduja yes, you are right, when i change the code it gives me an error and says that main.o no such an file or directory

Answer (score 3):

When you compile without the -c flag, gcc tries to link the program. Since the main function is most probably in the main.c and not in db.c, the linker fails when searching for the main function in db.c. This means that you need to tell the compiler that you just want output that is not yet linked, but translated into an object file and this is exactly what the -c flag does.

this results in what rajatkhanduja said:

```
db.o: db.cpp 
$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) db.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed the link rule.

You ought to have a first rule telling make how to link:

```
testing_OBJECTS = main.o db.o mod.o multiplex.o network.o networkinterfacemodule.o program.o service.o

testing$(EXEEXT): $(testing_OBJECTS)
    ld $(testing_OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

And *this* rule must be the precondition to `all`:

```
all: testing$(EXEEXT)
```

Futhermore, as all of your "*.o: *.cpp" rules are identical, you can specify a single rule and let `make` substitute the file names for you.
Ask if you want more datails on it.