# "Undefined reference to main" with main in a seperate script/rule

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

This is a possible dup of [makefile error: undefined reference to main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225118/makefile-error-undefined-reference-to-main) or [Undefined reference in main Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349928/undefined-reference-in-main-makefile) or a few others. Both crc64 and getWord are supporting files for mainProg, which contains my main function. When I try to run my make file I am getting the compilation error below regarding my rules for crc64.o. In the c file I have the include statements and header files laid out in this post [Creating your own header file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109964/creating-your-own-header-file-in-c) so I should not be having linking errors related to linking header to the body.

ERROR:
``` gcc -g -Wall -std=c99 crc64.o -o crc64
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function ``_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to ``main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status ```

Makefile

```
CC=gcc
COPTS=-g -Wall -std=c99
ALL=crc64 getWord mainProg
all: $(ALL)

crc64: crc64.o
   $(CC) $(COPTS) $^ -o $@
getWord: getWord.o
   $(CC) $(COPTS) $^ -o $@
mainProg: getWord.o crc64.o mainProg.o 
   $(CC) $(COPTS) $^ -o $@
crc64.o: crc64.c crc64.h
getWord.o: getWord.c getWord.h
mainProg.o: mainProg.c getWord.h crc64.h
.c.o:
   $(CC) -c $(COPTS) $<
```

Comment: in the makefile, use ':=' when defining a macro rather than '=' because when using '=' the macro will be re-evaluated each time it is invoked while the ':=' will only be evaluated once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are compiling `crc64` and `getWord` as if they were executables. As such, they need a `main` function.

Simply remove those two targets. You don't need them.

Also see @mafso's comment: you should use `CFLAGS` instrad of `COPTS`, to make sure the relevant [**implicit rules**](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) pick up the same options.

Comment: @mafso Good point. I incorporated that into the answer, with a link to some implicit rules documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
The following makefile would (probably) be just what your project needs
note: be sure to replace '<tab>' with the tab character


CC=gcc

COPTS := -g -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c99

LOPTS := -g

TARGET := mainProg

SRCS := $(wildcard:*.c)
OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)
HDRS := $(SRCS:.c=.h)

.PHONY: all

all: ${TARGET} 

${TARGET}: $(OBJS)
<tab>$(CC) $(COPTS) $^ -o $@

.c.o: #{HDRS}
<tab>$(CC) -c $(COPTS) -o $^ $<
```